# How to loop through SQL Server pivot query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Before start reading, if the following explanation is too long, and you won't read the code below.

Please you can override it and just look at the last line.

I have this normal looping query using cursor, and it works good.

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    Select top 100 percent
        [students].stu_id as StuID, Major_ID,MajorSeq,
        SysDate, Points
    From 
        [dbo].[StudentRegsterations] 
    inner join 
        [dbo].[students] on [dbo].[StudentRegsterations].Stu_ID = [dbo].[students].stu_id 
    order by 
        [Points] desc, [SysDate] desc;

DECLARE @StuID [int];
DECLARE @Major_ID [int];
DECLARE @MajorSeq [int];
DECLARE @SysDate [date];
DECLARE @Points [decimal](10, 2);

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @StuID, @Major_ID, @MajorSeq, @SysDate, @Points;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   --Do stuff with scalar values
   --InsertThisStudent()
   print CAST(@Points as varchar(10)) + '  -  ' + CAST(@SysDate as varchar(20))

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @StuID, @Major_ID, @MajorSeq, @SysDate, @Points;
END;

CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

This query above looping throw normal selection.

But if I changed it to pivot query gave me this following error.

> Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
>   Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

and the pivot query who causes the error is this.

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (Select top 100 percent
             [students].stu_id as StuID, SysDate, Points, MajorSeq, Major_ID
         From 
             [dbo].[StudentRegsterations] 
         inner join 
             [dbo].[students] on [dbo].[StudentRegsterations].Stu_ID = [dbo].[students].stu_id) WorkOrders
PIVOT
(
  max(Major_ID)
  FOR [MajorSeq] IN (
    [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
    [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20]
  )
) AS PivotTable 
order by [Points] desc,[SysDate] desc

DECLARE @StuID [int];
DECLARE @Major_ID [int];
DECLARE @MajorSeq [int];
DECLARE @SysDate [date];
DECLARE @Points [decimal](10, 2);
DECLARE @1 [int];DECLARE @2 [int];DECLARE @3 [int];DECLARE @4 [int];DECLARE @5 [int];DECLARE @6 [int];DECLARE @7 [int];
DECLARE @8 [int];DECLARE @9 [int];DECLARE @10 [int];DECLARE @11 [int];DECLARE @12 [int];DECLARE @13 [int];DECLARE @14 [int];
DECLARE @15 [int];DECLARE @16 [int];DECLARE @17 [int];DECLARE @18 [int];DECLARE @19 [int];DECLARE @20 [int];

OPEN db_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @StuID, @Major_ID, @MajorSeq, @SysDate, @Points,
@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12,@13,@14,@15,@16,@17,@18,@19,@20;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   --Do stuff with scalar values
   --InsertThisStudent()
   print CAST(@Points as varchar(10)) + '  -  ' + CAST(@SysDate as varchar(20))

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @StuID, @Major_ID, @MajorSeq, @SysDate, @Points, @1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12,@13,@14,@15,@16,@17,@18,@19,@20;
END;

CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Briefly all what I want, to looping through pivot query using whatever SQL Server way, using any small query sample, uncommitted with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the result from your pivot query to temp table (using `INTO #TempTable`) and loop #TempTable.

EDIT. However it should also work with your code. Maybe try to `CLOSE db_cursor` and execute it again. I think you have there already some definition of db_cursor that causes the issue.

Comment: you right my code have no essential error as you said. I'ts just tow columns (`@Major_ID, @MajorSeq`) not appear from pivot selection . because thay are fill the pivot columns `@1,@2,@3,` .... etc. Once I remove It the query get work correctly.